# dnu publish adds 2 packages folders to the output result

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, dnu

I am using dnu publish command but I have noticed that the output contains 2 packages folders as follow:

1 - approot\packages

2 - approot\src\"project name"\packages

Now one difference between the two folders is that folder # 1 contains only packages that matches the target framework so the size is really small whereas as folder # 2 contains everything for every package, thats why the size is too big. For example folder # 1 has a size of 11 MB whereas # 2 has a size of 120 MB.

I don't think IIS will be using folder # 2 but I don't know why it is been created in the first place.

Also I noticed that folder # 2 is also get created in Visual Studio.

I am on this version now: dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7

I know packages are downloaded to C:\Users\.dnx\packages so why would Visual Studio 2015 also including it in the project?

Comment: Is there any chance your project and solution directories are the same here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use --no-source switch as this one does not produce `src` folder at all.

Like this:
`dnu publish --no-source`

EDIT: (sorry missed second part of the question)
As I understand `dnu publish` includes all packages in publish package to create self contained package. This way of doing things ease deployment. You may also decide to deliver whole runtime as a package and have zero external dependencies on any installed or not tools on server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So when you publish you don't need the src folder? can you deploy the result of this command to IIS and that will work?

Comment: Your application is normal nuget package and you may find it under approot/packages/your_application. Check out also  "Publish from Visual Studio" http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html